# Custom Connector ( JSON result convert into Paramters )

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, openapi, power-automate

1. List item

I am a newbie in the azure environment. I am getting JSON response from my custom connector but I need to convert that JSON into parameters so I can use these parameters in further actions Can anybody know how is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use these parameters in further actions but you don't mention which type it's stored.

1.Stored as string. In this way the whole json is a string, it's not supported to select property. So you need parse it to Json with `Parse JSON` action then you will be able to select property. About the Parse JSON Schema, just click the `Use sample payload to generate schema` and paste your json value, it will generate. And select your property just use the `@{body('Parse_JSON')?['name']}`, it will work.

[image]

[image]

2.If it's stored as an `Object`, just use expression `variables('test1')['name']` to get it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joey, Without using Parse Json can we convert Json result into parameters in customer connector ?